# Simple contract Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: web3js

I create a very simple contract as follows:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.24 <0.6.0; 
contract Test {

// There is minimum and maximum bets.
uint constant MIN_BET = 0.01 ether;
uint constant MAX_AMOUNT = 300000 ether;

// 测试1
function getTest(uint modulo) external payable {

    // Validate input data ranges.
    uint amount = msg.value;
    require (modulo > 1 && modulo <= 100, "Modulo should be within range.");
    require (amount >= MIN_BET && amount <= MAX_AMOUNT, "Amount should be within range.");

}
}
```

Then I used `truffle compile`, `truffle migrate`, after that, I wrote a test file as followa:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
const json = require('../build/contracts/Test.json');
const utils = require('ethereumjs-util');
let accounts;
let contract;
let manager;
let result;
const interface = json['abi'];
const bytecode = json['bytecode'];
const address = '0x059F708ffFB51719074349A172838285BF1C33BF';
beforeEach(async () => {
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
manager = accounts[0];
contract = new web3.eth.Contract(interface, address, {from: manager});
});
describe('Test', () => {
it('get test', async () => {
result = await contract.methods.getTest(100).send({
from: manager,
value: web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether'),
gas: 500000
});
console.log('### result:');
console.log(result);
});
});
```

I ran "mocha test", then got this:

> Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:    {
>   "transactionHash":"0x6a21a921326725709e1d1cd549b862e9abc5faf691886d5c6d9081b89a2e9ff2",
>   "transactionIndex": 0,
>   "blockHash":"0x8ee0d6f54d2ea010d782400fa348e8b253e66a2f4ed54e04f36d992d326c5662",
>   "blockNumber": 6,      "from":
>   "0x99aa63cceea343c81ccff19e9366a67a5d3635cc",      "to":
>   "0x059f708fffb51719074349a172838285bf1c33bf",      "gasUsed": 21772,
>   "cumulativeGasUsed": 21772,      "contractAddress": null,      "logs":
>   [],      "status": true,      "logsBloom":
>   "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>   "v": "0x1b",   "r":
>   "0xda47199fde41e787bffb63ef1ab2275362914ccb673aac1333911f4f6f30997e", 
>   "s":
>   "0x38faafb77a25155c758d7c3fc998b8c9486c83136ef8dbd445c1be4996041dfc"
>   }

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the issue with the version of web3 you are using. Try web3@1.0.0-beta.34.
you can find the details here:   [could not be able to change my setmessage because (Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68740/could-not-be-able-to-change-my-setmessage-because-transaction-has-been-reverted/68788#68788)